# Approaching "window" correctly in Node test environment with JSDom

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, reactjs, jsdom

I'm testing my React app with [Tape](https://github.com/substack/tape) and JSDom, with the following module imported at the top of each test JS file:

```
import jsdom from 'jsdom'

function setupDom() {
  if (typeof document === 'undefined') {
    global.document = jsdom.jsdom('<html><body></body></html>');
    global.window = document.defaultView;
    global.navigator = window.navigator;
    global.WebSocket = function(){};
  }
}

setupDom();
```

However, in one of my React components, I import a [pathseg polyfill](https://github.com/progers/pathseg) like so:

```
import 'pathseg'
```

However, when I run the test, I receive this error:

```
    SVGPathSeg.prototype.classname = "SVGPathSeg";
        ^

ReferenceError: SVGPathSeg is not defined
```

Which, if I go the source of the error (in the polyfill), I see:

```
(function() { "use strict";
if (!("SVGPathSeg" in window)) {
    // Spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#paths-InterfaceSVGPathSeg
    window.SVGPathSeg = function(type, typeAsLetter, owningPathSegList) {
        this.pathSegType = type;
        this.pathSegTypeAsLetter = typeAsLetter;
        this._owningPathSegList = owningPathSegList;
    }

    SVGPathSeg.prototype.classname = "SVGPathSeg";
```

My question is, how can I fix this, and also, can I approach my testing setup differently to avoid this in the future?

Comment: You think could always get around this with some dirty copy/paste `global.SVGPathSeg = function(... ` in setupDom, but isn't this a good opportunity  to abandon the deprecated SVGPathSeg altogether in favour of the SVG Path Data API as mentioned in the pathseg documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Your test setup should not stick window properties in global. jsdom can theoretically handle this case - if you're using it correctly:

You should provide a whole test bundle to jsdom, like you'd test in a browser as well. This usually means you have to browserify your tests, then provide the final script file to jsdom (like you'd do in a normal browser). See also [this](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/1203#issuecomment-160725194) comment/thread on that practice.